# Openrefine and wikidata: how to get values (not reconciliation)

Tags: wikidata, openrefine

I was wondering if there's a way to take some values from wikidata through openrefine. For instance: I've got the wikidata ID of a painting. Inside Openrefine it is possible to create a new column with the wikidata author ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the **Add columns from reconciled values** operation. Note: you will need to reconcile your column (even if your column already contains Wikidata identifiers - in that case reconciliation should be quicker than usual).

[image: screencast of data extension]